# ClientDataSet para Excel

Tags: delphi, microsoft-excel, tclientdataset

Estou exportando um **clientdataset** para **excel** com a função ClientDataSetToExcelFile, porém uma das informações é CPF/CNPJ ex: 00112312312, ou seja, contém zeros(0) no inicio da string. Ao exportar o excel acaba removendo estes caracteres pois a célula é do tipo GERAL como padrão.

Aqui alimento a célula:

```
Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[iSheet].Cells[eline,(vCol+1)] := pQr.Fields[i].AsString;
```

Tentei utilizar  a seguinte instrução:

```
Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[iSheet].Cells[eline,(vCol+1)].NumberFormat := '@';
```

No excel funciona, mas no meu caso substituiu os valores por "64" e logicamente não funcionou nada.

Utilizo delphi XE...

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia henriquew..Tudo certinho?? :)
Cara eu acho que é só trocar a ORDEM dos comandos..
**Primeiro voce FORMATA A CELULA**

```
ObjetoExcelApplication.Range[Cel,Cel].NumberFormat:= '@';<br>
```

**Depois tu coloca o VALOR nela**

```
ObjetoExcelApplication.Range[Cel,Cel].Value := Texto;
```

Aqui deu certo..
testa ai e vê se funciona :)

Comment: Buenas Ricardo, na verdade no meu exemplo tentei alterar a ordem, mas não funcionou, sempre ele substitui o valor da celula por 64, acredito que seja o valor ascii de @... você utiliza o Delphi XE também?

Comment: Falaaaa..:).. Cara testei com DELPHI 7 .. Na Maquina Virtual que tenho o Delphi CE instalado, não tem ofice.. :(

Comment: Já tive esse problema. O Excel exibe 64, mas se você especificar outro formato, o conteúdo está correto. Eu costumo incluir um apóstrofe iniciando o conteúdo pra ficar como texto.

Answer (score 0):

```
Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[iSheet].Cells[eline,(vCol+1)].NumberFormat := 'Texto';
Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[iSheet].Cells[eline,(vCol+1)] := pQr.Fields[i].AsString;
```